# Selecting distinct values from multiple column of a table with their count

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, ms-access

i want to to select distinct values from multiple columns of same table with their count 
example
[image]

and the output should be like this

[image]

Comment: Which database are you using: MySQL; SQL Server; or MS Access?

Comment: Which database? And why do you need this? Seems like unclustered data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question appears to be off-topic because it is just a programming "spec", with no evidence that you have done any research into the topic or have made any effort to solve it yourself. Please [edit] your question to show [1] the topic(s) you have searched for, and/or [2] the things you have tried and why they didn't work. If "you have no idea where to begin" then please read a book on SQL or do some online tutorials and come back when you have an actual question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Get all column values to one row and find the count

**SQL SERVER**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT COL1 Name
   FROM YOURTABLE
   UNION ALL
   SELECT COL2
   FROM YOURTABLE
   UNION ALL
   SELECT COL3
   FROM YOURTABLE
   UNION ALL
   SELECT COL4
   FROM YOURTABLE
   UNION ALL
   SELECT COL6
   FROM YOURTABLE
   UNION ALL
   SELECT COL7
   FROM YOURTABLE
)
SELECT DISTINCT Name,COUNT(Name) OVER(PARTITION BY Name) [COUNT]
FROM CTE
```

**MYSQL**

```
SELECT Name,COUNT(*) [COUNT]
(
   SELECT COL1 Name
   FROM #TEMP
   UNION ALL
   SELECT COL2
   FROM #TEMP  
   UNION ALL
   SELECT COL3
   FROM #TEMP  
   UNION ALL
   SELECT COL4
   FROM #TEMP  
   UNION ALL
   SELECT COL6
   FROM #TEMP  
   UNION ALL
   SELECT COL7
   FROM #TEMP      
)TAB   
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: Better use `group by` and `count` the `name` . `Mysql` doesn't support over clause +1.

Comment: i just tried the above query in sql server. and it works for me. thanks for the answer

Comment: @VivekMaru - Come on man atleast tag your question's properly. In comments you said you are using `Mysql`. Here you are using `sql server`

Comment: Downvoter? Why down vote? I have added solution for both SQl Server and MYSQL

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP says in his comment that he uses MYSQL this should work

```
SELECT data,COUNT(data)
FROM  
(
   SELECT COL1 data
   FROM tableso
   UNION ALL
   SELECT COL2
   FROM tableso
   UNION ALL
   SELECT COL3
   FROM tableso
   UNION ALL
   SELECT COL4
   FROM tableso
   UNION ALL
   SELECT COL6
   FROM tableso
   UNION ALL
   SELECT COL7
   FROM tableso
) finaltable group by data;
```

SQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f8cf/10

I dont think the accepted answer works on MYSQL

**UPDATE:**

The op has changed his mind about the database(to MSSQL) and the accepted answer has both db versions

Comment: `Distinct` is not needed here

Comment: this is for sql server

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `Sql Server` too, will suggest you this way

Use `Table valued constructor` to convert the columns to rows then `count` the `name`

This will avoid multiple table scan's.

```
SELECT name,
       [count]=Count(1)
FROM   yourtable
       CROSS apply (VALUES (col1),(COL2),(col3),(col4),(COL6),(col7)) cs (name)
GROUP  BY name
```

**Note :** This will not work in `Mysql`

### [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3360/1)